# how to initialize and use a 2d struct in c

Tags: c, struct, 2d

So what i am trying to do is have an array of lists, here is my code:

```
typedef struct stackList{
    List * list;
} stack;

int main(){
    int x;
    stack ** stackTable;

    for(x=0;x<100;x++) 
        stackTable[x]=malloc(sizeof(stack*)*100);
}
```

i get a segmentation fault on the for loop, i would assume the way i am trying to use the struct is wrong. Would i rather in the defintion of the struct use List ** list;
or is there a way to use it the way i am trying to use it

Comment: stackTable refers to nowhere and you are using it inside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You get segmentation fault because you're accessing stackTable while it is uninitialized. You can't know to what address of memory it points, and you haven't allocated an array to hold the pointers that you are dereferencing.

You need to make *stackTable* point to a valid array of pointers, in this case I think is convenient to make it be an array:

```
Stack* stackTable[100];
```

Now you have an array of pointers to *Stack*, you can initialize them.

If instead you have just temporarily an array large 100, and you need to make it grow in future, that's how dynamically allocating it:

```
Stack** stackTable= malloc(100*sizeof(Stack*));
```

Comment: say i have to increase the size of the stack, do i realloc

Comment: If the array has to grow you should use dynamic allocation. I edited the question to add an example.

Answer (score -1):

Before trying too hard to play with pointers and dynamic memory I might suggest writing some basic programs using basic 2d arrays. For instance:

```
char array2d[10][10];
```

Once you're confortable inserting elements into this array, extracting elements, etc, you can apply all of the same principles to any type.

Comment: i am comfortable doing that stuff, i think i got what i needed. I changed the struct to this:  
    typedef struct stackList{
        List * list;
        List * nextList;
    } stack;

Comment: @s.brookes While it might be an useful advice, your answer should really be a comment.

Comment: @Armin Gotchya. Sorry about that.